# How to overload '-' operator to copy strings

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, operator-overloading

**The question here is**

> Write a program to construct a class "MyString" which has one string and length of that string as its data members. now overload '-' operator to copy the string into another string.

I'm not understanding how to do this..I've written a code which when i'm trying to use in main its showing the following **error**:

> Error 1   Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

**my code is:**

```
public class MyString
{       
    public string s="SILADITYA";
    //public string this[string s]{ get; set; }

    public static string operator -(string s1, MyString m)
    {
        s1 = String.Copy(m.s);
        return s1;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyString m = new MyString();

        string s1 = s1 - m.s;

    }
}
```

please tell me how can I overload this opoerator

Comment: There is a sample from MSDN, how to overload operator : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Oh my goodness NEVER DO THIS.  That is the worst use of operator overloading I've ever seen. That violates every guideline about the correct and proper use of operator overloads. If some book or teacher is suggesting that you do this, get a better book or a better teacher, because the one you have is awful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct just make this change while calling it from `Main`

```
 string s1 = string.Empty;
 s1 = s1 - m;
```

It was failing since your operator overload expects a `string and MyString` parameters and you were supplying `String and String`